# Adding a span class to a string concatenated in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have some javascript code that users the ternary operator to determine the first part of a message variable.

```
response.answer == "stack overflow" ? message = "blah blah some message." : message = "blah blah some other message" + some variable;
```

Once that ternary operator's complete, I then concatenate more onto the string.

```
message += " About me: my name's Blah blah. Contact me on @blah blah Twitter. This game was made with blah blah."
```

How would you add a span class to the string contained in the message variable so that it can be styled?

Comment: Please refine your question... what do you mean by "span class"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new element and set it's `innerHTML` to the message.

```
var span = document.createElement('span');

span.innerHTML = message;
span.className = 'myClass';

document.getElementById('targetContainer').appendChild(span);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to add a span tag with a class to final message variable, then you can do like this

```
message += " Abou ..... "; // after this line add
message = "<span class='yourclassname'>" + message + "</span>";
```

then you can add this message html to your targert container as

```
document.getElementById("targetContainer").innerHTML = message;
```